# Fine Uploader - using both Direct S3 and Traditional in same project

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I have an existing FineUploader implementation for small files using the Traditional (upload-to-server) version which is working great. However, I'd like to also allow Direct S3 uploads from a different part of the application which deals with large attachments, without rewriting the existing code for small files.

Is there some way to allow both Direct S3 and Traditional uploads to work alongside each other? This is a single-page application, so I can't just load one or the other fine-uploader versions depending on which page I'm on.

I tried just including both fine-uploader JS files, but it seemed to break my existing code.

Client-side code:

```
$uploadContainer = this.$('.uploader')
$uploadButton = this.$('.upload-button')
$uploadContainer.fineUploader(
  request:
    endpoint: @uploadUrl
    inputName: @inputName
    params:
      authenticity_token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  button: $uploadButton
).on 'complete', (event, id, fileName, response) =>
  @get('controller').receiveUpload(response)
```

Comment: What specific error message are you seeing if you attempt to include multiple builds of the same version on the same page?  Also, which builds are you attempting to load?  Are these custom built-versions via the web-based builder?

Comment: Thanks! Just tried it again. 1. Downloaded custom build from web-based builder of the Traditional style and tested my traditional setup with that version - it still worked fine. 2. Downloaded an S3 custom build (did not change default checkboxes either time) of 4.3.1 and included that JS file in my application as well (after renaming it of course). Then when I try to click my upload button on my Traditional upload form, I get this error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8oeuahd49xe8q4/Screenshot%202014-02-21%2015.19.30.png which is actually coming from the S3 JS file, not the Trad one.

Comment: This is most likely caused by your integration code.  Please show your integration client-side code when you have both versions loaded.

Comment: Added it to the original question. Nothing fancy really, and the call is still to fineUploader() not fineUploaderS3().

Comment: And just so it's clear - this code works fine if I just remove the fineUploader S3 JS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good find, @Melinda.

Fine Uploader lives within a custom-named namespace so that it does not conflict with other potential global variables, this is the `qq` namespace (historically named). What is happening is that each custom build is redeclaring this namespace along with all member objects when you include it in the `<script>` tags on your page.

I've opened up [an issue on our bug tracker](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1144) that explains the issue in more technical details, and we're looking to prioritize a fix to the customize page so that in the future no one will have this issue.

Comment: In the meantime -- since you are a licenseholder -- if you would like us to assemble a custom build for you with both the traditional and S3 endpoints, please feel free to email licensing@fineuploader.com an email.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! That would be wonderful, and I'll send over an email.